# Why is the font changed when exporting a word-file to pdf?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, export-to-pdf

We use this code in access-vba to convert our word to a pdf:

```
    Set w_app = CreateObject("word.application")
    w_app.Documents.Open(fileName:="C:\Temp\Test.docx")
    w_app.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat "c:\Temp\test.pdf", wdExportFormatPDF, _
                                             OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
                                             Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
                                             IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
                                             DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:=True, useIso19005_1:=false
```

But when we open the pdf, all the text which was written with the font: "Apercu Pro" has changed to the font: "Segoe Script".

This does not happen when we use Office-Word to manually export the file.

Strangly, it also does work fine when the font "Apercu Pro" in !not! installed in windows.

What we already tried:

- We changed every single parameter of ExportAsFixedFormat => no effect
- We used the function ExportAsFixedFormat2 instead of ExportAsFixedFormat => no effect
- Tried to use w_app.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2("c:\Temp\test.pdf", EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False) instead of ExportAsFixedFormat  => no effect

Comment: Have you tried to use a VBA macro recorder to find out what parameters are required to get the job done correctly?

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem.  It had the right font on my system

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev: No we didnt. But we will try it.

Comment: @mazoula: There might be problems with the font-file. We try to get a new one.

Comment: Couldn't replicate suggests you may need to apply the microsoft fix and turn everything off and on and recheck your steps.  I should have mentioned I used Access 2016 on windows.  I forget the one Apercu font I downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not really find out what the problem was exactly but my solution was to deinstall the .otf-Version (OpenType format) of the font and instead install the .ttf-Version (True type format).

Answer (score 1):

Just for future readers: I had the same problem even though I was already using a `.ttf` file, so the accepted answer didn't work for me.

I fixed it by using a static `.ttf` version of the font (= fixed weight), instead of a variable one (= supports all weights etc.).